# For loop over fraction of files with python

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a way to create a for loop that executes over a fraction of files?
In this case, I would like to move 1/5 (the last 1/5 of the files) of all my images in subfolders to another folder with its subfolders. I have started some, but need help.

```
import os

path = 'pictures/'
outpath = 'oldpictures/'

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(path):
    new_dir = root.replace(path, outpath, 1)
    if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
        os.mkdir(new_dir)
    for filename in filenames: #Is it here that I can loop over the last fraction of all the files somehow?
        os.system(mv {0} {1}.format(filename, new_dir)) #Dunno if this is the best way either or if it is possible.
```

Comment: Does it have to be the last 20%, or is that just an example. Do an arbitrary 20% is easier... you just keep a counter and move every 5th file you traverse.

Comment: Do a count of files first say `cnt`. Get a counter inside for loop and every time do `counter += 1`. Whenever `counter > 0.8 * cnt` start moving files `else continue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just slice `filenames` accordingly:

```
# Loop through the last ~1/5 of filenames
for filename in filenames[4*len(filenames)//5:]:
    ...
```

You may need to make adjustments if there is specific rounding behavior you expect.

Also, don't use `os.system()` to move files. Use [`os.rename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename).